# What's the difference between saveUninitialized and resave?

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

The session middleware for Express provides [several configurable options](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

**resave**: 'Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the session was never modified during the request.'

**saveUninitialized**: 'Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified.'

It appears that both options are for saving unmodified sessions. **What's the difference?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When use saveUninitialized and resave in express-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381401/when-use-saveuninitialized-and-resave-in-express-session)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought I would start off with a basic answer, my bit of understanding so far, and improve it together. Important question been 'dead' for too long.

From [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session#options) I understand the difference is:

(Unmodified 'state' is different to uninitialized state)

**resave**: For any request made

- Nothing in the session needs to change (no login etc).
- Change of session required (logged in)

"Forces session to be saved even when unmodified"

**saveUninitialized**: Is about the state of the session, if its still in the uninitialized state.

- Not modified only, nothing in the session needs to change (no login etc).

"Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified."

Answer (score 4):

Basically, a session is saved in the store only when it is modified; if you **add**, **delete** or **edit** a session cookie (eg: `req.session.test = 'some value'`). If you want all the sessions to be saved in store, even if they don't have any modifications go with `saveUninitialized: true`.

Now, re-saving also happens only when session variables/cookies changes. If you want to save then always go ahead with `resave: true`

Comment: What if saveUninitialized value is "True" but a session is not modified at all. I know that it would store the session in the database but would a session cookie still get set?