# What's exactly the meaning of "saveUninitialized","resave" and "rolling" properties in express-session?

Tags: node.js, express

Recently，I'm learning about the middleware "express-session" of express, I want to understand all properties in the given options.But when I read about the API of `express-session`, I'm confused with the three

properties:`saveUninitialized`, `resave` and `rolling`.

They all have an effect on cookie setting or session operation, so what's the difference and connection of them?

Hope somebody can help me to distinguish them,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40381401/when-use-saveuninitialized-and-resave-in-express-session

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385726/whats-the-difference-between-saveuninitialized-and-resave

Comment: You should accept the answer, it is really good.

Answer (score 16):

When a modern browser makes a request, it appends all cookies that match the current domain (website) in the `Cookie` header. Here's an example of what my browser might send if I visit stackoverflow.com:

`Cookie: acct=1234`

No cookies are sent by the browser when you visit a site for the first time. In that case (and if the owner wanted to utilise cookies to track user sessions, for example) the server will commonly respond with a `Set-Cookie` header, something like this:

`Set-Cookie: acct=5678; expires=Sat, 15 May 2050 15:32:57 GMT; domain=.stackoverflow.com`

(It can also append `path`, `secure`, and `HttpOnly` options, all explained [here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/)) I'm simplifying but, by default, `express-session` only sends `Set-Cookie` when you visit a site for the first time.

If `rolling` is `true`, it will be sent every time. This has the desired side-effect of continuously rolling forward the expiration of the cookie with every page refresh. The new expiration date is determined by adding `maxAge` to the current server time.

If you alter the `req.session` object, it will be saved back to the session store at the end of the request; otherwise it will not be saved. Setting `resave` to `true` forces it to be saved everytime, even if no changes were made. It might seem illogical but certain stores might require this (although, having looked through the list, it seems that none currently do).

When a cookie is set for the first time, a new session object is created in memory and saved to the store at the end of the request. This can take up a lot of space in the db if you have many people visiting and then bouncing without performing any meaningful action like logging in. You can choose to only save sessions if they deviate from the default session object (ie. if you've modified it, like setting `req.session.user = user;` on login) by setting `saveUninitialized` to `false`.

Something to be aware of is certain combinations of these values (along with others) might produce unexpected behaviour. For example, the documentation states:

> When this option [rolling] is set to true but the saveUninitialized option is set to false, the cookie will not be set on a response with an uninitialized session.

Comment: Can we talk, I have few doubts?