# What is the purpose of these 2 properties resave and saveUninitialized in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, single-page-application

I have used this and it works but still, I am not clear that what resave and saveUninitialized are? I have read all the theories but still, I don't get it.

In the light of my code, how should I play with it so I understand the usage of these 2 properties?

Code:

```
var express= require('express')
var eApp= express();
var session= require('express-session');
var bodyparser= require('body-parser');

eApp.use(session({secret: 'hunainkey', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));
//eApp.use(cookieParser());

eApp.use(bodyparser.json());

eApp.get('/get/:user', (req, res) => 
{
    req.session.user= req.params.user; 
    res.send("Session set");
});

eApp.get('/', (req, res) => 
{
    res.send(req.session.user);
});

eApp.listen(1000, () => console.log('nodeapp5 is listening on port 1000'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check express session option documentation for more information
https://github.com/expressjs/session

> #### saveUninitialized
>
> Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store.

> #### resave
>
> Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the session was never modified during the request.

User [cfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3090337/cfl) also explains here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36688600/3151646

> (Unmodified 'state' is different to uninitialized state)
>
> **resave**: For any request made
>
> - Nothing in the session needs to change (no login etc).
> - Change of session required (logged in)
>
> "Forces session to be saved even when unmodified"
>
> **saveUninitialized**: Is about the state of the session, if its still in the uninitialized state.
>
> - Not modified only, nothing in the session needs to change (no login etc).
>
> "Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified."